# How to get value of user id from a session in slim session manager in PHP?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, slim

I am developing an application in Slim framework where I set sessions where I log the user in. During logging in, i encode the value of user id in the session. Later in functions, I have to retrieve the user id from the sessions to use it in my functions.

Here is the my code:

create session

```
$app->session->put('current_user', [1, 'hoge_user']);
```

get session

```
$current_user = $app->session->get('current_user');
```

delete session

```
$app->session->forget('current_user');
```

Now, while getting a session, how do I echo the value '1' which I have set while creating the session?

Answer (score 1):

The `1` inside the array, would be the index 0 in the array so you would access this through

```
$current_user = $app->session->get('current_user');
echo $current_user[0]; // 1
echo $current_user[1]; // hoge_user
```

A small hint you can also define how you access this value, a better approach would be to:

```
$app->session->put('current_user', ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'hoge_user']);

$current_user = $app->session->get('current_user');

echo $current_user['id'];
```

Or you may add two sessions variables.